# How to get text from web elements using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have HTML code as in below and I am trying to extract value using xpath.

```
<input id="searchCriteriaForm:memberNumber" name="searchCriteriaForm:memberNumber" type="text" value="143256789" maxlength="17" size="15" class="inputText">
```

My code is

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="searchCriteriaForm:memberNumber"]').text)
```

code is not printing anything and no exception. I am expecting to print value "143256789'

let me know what's wrong with my code statement.

Comment: <input id="searchCriteriaForm:memberNumber" name="searchCriteriaForm:memberNumber" type="text" value="125690" maxlength="17" size="15" class="inputText">

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is not part of the text content - it is inside the `value` attribute of the tag.

You can use `.get_attribute('value')` instead of `.text`

[.get_attribute() docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)